# How can I use categorical one-hot labels for training with Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, one-hot-encoding

I have inputs that look like this:

```
[
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
...]
```

of shape `(1, num_samples, num_features)`, and labels that look like this:

```
[
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
...]
```

of shape `(1, num_samples, 2)`.

However, when I try to run the following Keras code, I get this error:
`ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 8038, 2)`. From what I've read, this appears to stem from the fact that my labels are 2D, and not simply integers. Is this correct, and if so, *how can I use one-hot labels with Keras?*

Here's the code:

```
num_features = 463
trX = np.random(8038, num_features)
trY = # one-hot array of shape (8038, 2) as described above

def keras_builder():  #generator to build the inputs
    while(1):
        x = np.reshape(trX, (1,) + np.shape(trX))
        y = np.reshape(trY, (1,) + np.shape(trY))
        print(np.shape(x)) # (1, 8038, 463)
        print(np.shape(y)) # (1, 8038, 2)
        yield x, y

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_dim = num_features))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(keras_builder(), samples_per_epoch = 1, nb_epoch=3, verbose = 2, nb_worker = 1)
```

Which promptly throws the error above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 35, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(keras_builder(), samples_per_epoch = 1, nb_epoch=3, verbose = 2, nb_worker = 1)
  ...
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 8038, 2)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of things that do not add up.

I assume that you are trying to solve a sequential classification task, i.e. your data is shaped as `(<batch size>, <sequence length>, <feature length>)`.

In your batch generator you create a batch consisting of one sequence of length 8038 and 463 features per sequence element. You create a matching Y batch to compare against, consisting of one sequence with 8038 elements, each of size 2.

Your problem is that `Y` does not match up with the output of the last layer. Your `Y` is 3-dimensional while the output of your model is only 2-dimensional: `Y.shape = (1, 8038, 2)` does not match `dense_1.shape = (1,1)`. This explains the error message you get.

The solution to this: you need to enable `return_sequences=True` in the LSTM layer to return a sequence instead of only the last element (effectively removing the time-dimension). This would give an output shape of `(1, 8038, 100)` at the LSTM layer. Since the `Dense` layer is not able to handle sequential data you need to apply it to each sequence element individually which is done by wrapping it in a [`TimeDistributed`](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) wrapper. This then gives your model the output shape `(1, 8038, 1)`.

Your model should look like this:

```
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_dim=num_features, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
```

This can be easily spotted when examining the summary of the model:

```
print(model.summary())
```